# custom login form, guide me

Tags: users, login

i need to make a custom login form but i got a hard time finding references from my google search so i hope someone here is able to point towards some links to lay the grounds for me.

A standard wordpress registration normaly contains:

- Username
- Password
- Email

well thats not enough for my needs :(

i need something like:

- Username
- First name
- Last name
- Phone number
- Car Id
- bool values for salary
- Email
- password

so.... making a custom login form like this is pretty easy but i'm pretty new to wordpress so i thought it better to ask some veterans in here for the proporway of doing it.

can someone post some links for the proper way to customize the login form like this?

first should i put all the none standard user info in the meta table?

second how would i go about adding these fields for the users to update them in the user settings section (proper wordpress way)?

//Alexander

thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor english :/

Comment: Did you try something? Search Google for such tutorials. Here is one on [digwp.com](http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code/)

Comment: i've already seen his tutorial and it has nothing to do with adding additional fields to the registration and calling the additional info to the user settings?

Comment: You mean how do you customize the registration form: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form

Comment: Also you want to customize the user profile page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/show_user_profile

Comment: thanks user42826 :D those links is very useful.... i should have searched the codex along with google..... but THANKS! :D

Answer (score 0):

Building on what others have already mentioned in the comments - There is a tutorial which uses WordPress native action hooks `register_form`, `registration_errors` and `user_register` to help you out:

[Add Fields to WordPress Registration Form Tutorial](http://sharethingz.com/wordpress/add-fields-to-wordpress-registration-form/)